# C++ template metaprogramming: how to deduce type in expression pattern

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, type-deduction

I am want a static check of the parameter type of lambdas. I've written this code below and it seems to produce the correct result.

```
struct B { };
auto lamBc = [](B const& b) { std::cout << "lambda B const" << std::endl; };

template<typename ClosureType, typename R, typename Arg>
constexpr auto ArgType(R (ClosureType::*)(Arg) const)->Arg;

template <typename T>
using ArgType_t = decltype(ArgType(&T::operator()));

// ArgType_t<lamBc> is "reference to B const"
```

However, I noticed that, for example, the standard library uses class template specialization to extract the referred-to type from a reference type in `std::remove_reference`. So I tried that approach and it also seems to produce the correct result.

```
template<typename L>
struct ArgType2;

template<typename ClosureType, typename R, typename Arg>
struct ArgType2<R (ClosureType::*)(Arg) const>
{
    typedef Arg type;
};

template <typename T>
using ArgType2_t = typename ArgType2<decltype(&T::operator())>::type;

// ArgType2_t<lamBc> is also "reference to B const"
```

My questions are: Which is the standard way to extract types from a pattern expression? What are the trade-offs in either approach?

Comment: Personally, I do not see any significant differences between two approaches so it looks like a matter of style for me...

Comment: Since we're speaking of style anyhow, you may want to do `using type = Arg`, not `typedef Arg type`.

Comment: Using return type of function allows deduction of parameters. Specialization is more strict. In your case, it is interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your approaches are valid, interchangeable and lead to the same result (deduce the type of the parameter lambda accepts).

For type traits it is required by the standard (see *23.15.1 Requirements*) that:

> 1. A UnaryTypeTrait describes a property of a type. **It shall be a class template** that takes one template type argument and, optionally, additional arguments that help define the property being described. ...
> 2. A BinaryTypeTrait describes a relationship between two types. **It shall be a class template** that takes two template type arguments
>      and, optionally, additional arguments that help define the
>      relationship being described. ...
> 3. A TransformationTrait modifies a property of a type. **It shall be a class template** that takes one template type argument and, optionally, additional arguments that help define the modification. ...

I suppose that this requirement appeared mostly for historical reasons as `decltype` functionality was introduced after type traits had been proposed (and these type traits were based on type traits from *boost* which had been created even earlier, see, for example, [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1424.htm)).

Also, note, that class templates are more flexible for general purpose type traits than the logic based on functions declarations and `decltype`.

The main point is that with *C++11* and later in your particular case you are free to use the way which is the most convenient and reflects the programming logic better.

Answer (score 0):

They are both "standard", the `decltype()` way is simply available in modern C++ variants, the PTS method was the only way to do this sort of things under the original C++ standard.